# Atom ESLint ignore server side language code

Tags: atom-editor, eslint

I'm using Atom Editor with ESLint on Mac. I need to lint html files that have script tags so I installed eslint-plugin-html and linter-eslint. However, some of my html files have django code in them and ESLint reports an error. *Parsing error. Unexpected token %*. Please advise how can ESLint ignore such server side code. Here is what my html file looks like

```
// some html here
<script>
    var foo = {
        {% for item in items %}
            {% if item == "foo" %}
            'foo': 'foo'
            // etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

A. Disable linting for specific [lines, sections of code, or an entire file](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments)

B. Disable linting for [specific file extensions](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-file-extensions-to-lint)

C. Avoid having django syntax within `<script>` tags.

One way to do this is get the data into a javascript variable then manipulate it in javascript.

**views.py**

```
def myview(request):
    some_django_data = json.dumps(geodata)
    ...
```

**template.html**

```
<script>
  var foo = JSON.parse('{{ some_django_data|safe }}')
</script>
<script scr="/path/to/myscript.js"></script>
```

**myscript.js**

```
foo.forEach(myFunc);
```